# Handle user-raised deprecation warning by pylint

Tags: python, pylint

Is there a way to tell pylint that it must show warning message when it see user-defined deprecation warning?

I've tried warnings.warn, DeprecationWarning - but pylint ignores them.

Comment: Have you written such a checker as proposed in @Alex Martelli's answer?

Comment: @hardmooth nope, I didn't get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `warnings.warn` &c are intended to happen at runtime, Pylint by default doesn't see them as anything strange.  To change that I think you need to follow the (advanced and scarce) docs for [writing your own checker](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual#writing-your-own-checker), with which you can emit warnings on any characteristics of the sources (either the raw ones or the AST-compiled level thereof).